# Use a decorator to turn a function into a generator in Python

Tags: python, generator, decorator

Is there a way for a decorator to convert the function below into a generator?

```
@decorator_that_makes_func_into_generator
def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        print n,
        n = n - 1
```

The function can be modified if necessary. Note that the function does not have a yield statement, otherwise it would already be a generator.

Comment: If you are really crazy you can always [patch the bytecode at runtime](http://www.jonathon-vogel.com/posts/patching_function_bytecode_with_python/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If you can't change the source** of `countdown`, you'll have to capture the output:

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

def decorator_that_makes_func_into_generator(func):
    def wrapper(*a, **ka):
        # Temporarily redirect all output to StringIO instance (intr)
        ts, intr = sys.stdout, StringIO()
        sys.stdout = intr
        func(*a, **ka)
        # Restore normal stdout from backup (ts)
        sys.stdout = ts
        # Get output from intr, split it by whitespace and use it as generator
        yield from intr.getvalue().split()

    return wrapper

@decorator_that_makes_func_into_generator
def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        print(n)
        n = n - 1

print(countdown(5), list(countdown(5)))
# <generator object wrapper at 0x01E09058> ['5', '4', '3', '2', '1']
```

**If you can change the function** and if you want to return something from `countdown` (`list` or other sequence type) and *then* create a generator from the returned object, decorator'd look like

```
def decorator_that_makes_func_into_generator(func):
    def wrapper(*a, **ka):
        yield from func(*a, **ka)
    return wrapper
```

Note: the awesome `yield from` was introduced in Python 3.3, on older versions use plain loop instead:

```
for x in func(*a, **ka): 
    yield x
```

Example:

```
@decorator_that_makes_func_into_generator
def countdown(n):
    res = []
    while n > 0:
        res.append(n)
        n = n - 1
    return res

print(type(countdown(5)), list(countdown(5))) 
# Output: <class 'generator'> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Nothing stops you from applying `decorator_that_makes_func_into_generator` to a generator:

```
@decorator_that_makes_func_into_generator
def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        yield n
        n = n - 1

print(type(countdown(5)), list(countdown(5))) 
# Outputs <class 'generator'> [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Nice! Probably for what he wants a `return iter(func(*a, **ka))` would be enough for the wrapper function (which wouldn't return a generator but would be deferred as well).

Comment: @frostnational, can you document the code to explain what is going on in the decorator function. This will really help

Comment: @user2979872 updated. (I assume you know how the decorators work)

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot change the body of that function, I'm afraid this is way too hard.

The function you are trying to wrap is not a generator, even if you wrap it into a generator, this function will be executed form beginning to the end in one go. Presumably you don't want that.

What can you do theoretically?

- run it under debugger
- run it under trace, line by line
- access function source, modify it, compile to bytecode
- modify bytecode
- override `print()` (easier in Python3)
- use stackless python to save and restore stack at arbitrary point